# Meteor sort case insensitive

Tags: javascript, mongodb, underscore.js, meteor

Is there a way to do a case-insensitive sort of a Meteor collection? If so, what code would I add to the following?

```
  var movies = Movies.find({}, {sort: {name: 1}});
```

Or is the only alternative right now to use Underscore (or some other vanilla JS) on the fetched data?

```
var movies = Movies.find().fetch(); 
return _.sortBy(movies, function(movie) {
// do your sorting here
});
```

Comment: agree with underscore fallback, it's 2016 and we still have to use that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB (at least as at 2.2.0) does not support case-insensitive indexes.

A common basic approach is to add an indexed lowercase version of the field you want to search on, and then lowercase search terms when searching from your application.  You could update the search field when your documents are inserted/updated.

A more flexible search could take this further by tokenizing the original field into multiple indexed search terms using stemming, stopwords, and other search strategies.

See also:
 [Full text search in MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo).

You can watch or vote on the [SERVER-90](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90) feature request ("Case-insensitive index") in the MongoDB issue tracker.